# Accessing DOM object in Node JS

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js

I am using a code snippet from a Github repository by Microsoft (https://github.com/microsoft/customvision-tfjs) for using a Tensorflow.js model in Node JS.

Here they are using document.getElementById() to access an image element and then passing it to a function for predication, but it's written between Node.js code where DOM is not available. is this code incorrect? or is there a way to access HTML elements in Node JS

```
const cvstfjs = require('@microsoft/customvision-tfjs');

async function doThings() {
  let model = new cvstfjs.ObjectDetectionModel();
  await model.loadModelAsync('model.json');
  const image = document.getElementById('image');
  const result = await model.executeAsync(image);
  return result;
}

doThings().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: How do you know it can't run in the browser and that it has to be run in node.js?

Comment: @CodyＧ The Github Repository tells the user to use npm to download module and then use this code to load the module and run object detection model

Comment: npm can be used to download browser (client side) modules --- usually a bundler is used, or they can be served statically through a web server (such as node) if they are pre-built.

Comment: @CodyＧ Thanks, i didn't knew that. But does "require" can be used within a web page? Also the code snippet was using "import" to import the module but i changed it to require because of Error :  Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Just use `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@1.3.2/dist/tf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/customvision-tfjs"></script>` since you're not using a bundler like `webpack` --- you are right in saying that node.js does not support `import` --- I'm not sure what will happen after you include those scripts, I assume `cvstfjs` will be available globally

Comment: @CodyＧ Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: No problem! Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use TF in the browser via [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and operate DOM as usual

or if you want a server-side fun use cheerio library.

```
npm i cheerio

const cheerio = require('cheerio')

var html = await fs.readFile('./dong.html')

const $ = cheerio.load(html.toString())

$('#element').text()
```